# How can I add a separate damage die to my homebrew magic item so that it rolls two separate dice on D&D Beyond's new dice roller?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage, dice, dnd-beyond

How can I add a separate damage die to my homebrew magic item so that it rolls two separate dice on D&D Beyond's new dice roller?

I got curious about for when my paladin reaches level 11/warlock 2 and gets a permanent 1d8 radiant damage from the Improved Divine Smite feature all the time. My main weapon is magical gifted by my warlock patron, so I'm looking to see if it's possible to add the extra dice as a feature so it's properly displayed and usable in D&D Beyond's dice roller feature. I can't figure out the right combo in the magic item creation page.

Comment: Divine Smite is not a magic weapon property - isn't that extra d8 added automatically in the damage calculation for your attack actions? I feel like it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a 1d8 radiant damage to a magic weapon is fairly straight forward:

- Add a modifier
- Set Type to Damage
- Set Subtype to Radiant
- Dice count to 1
- and Dice Type to d8

This should make the d8 radiant damage be added as a note on the attack option.

However, this doesn't make it automatically rolled when you roll for damage (this might have something to do with dice and mixed damage types). There is a workaround for this though, but it only works when the damage type doesn't matter and you're not using the versatile option. Set up a custom attack action.

Hit manage custom, and create a new action option. You'll want to set Range to Melee, Stat to STR, and Activation type to Action and mark Proficient and Display as Attack. Then set Dice Count to 2 and Dice Type to d8. You can use Fixed Value (to the right of the dice values) to add a static bonus to the damage roll, such as from Dueling. And give it a name so you remember what the attack option is. This will at least give you a conveniently accessible 2d8 + STR damage roll.

Answer (score 1):

#### The feature you describe is currently not supported.

I’m pretty familiar with DnDBeyond’s home brew tools. As of right now, there is no way  to have multiple types of damage dice display in the dice roller button for a weapon. *For now, it can only display the base damage die of the chosen weapon type*. You will have to use the manual dice roller on the left side of the character sheet for now, or sling some real dice.